# Make text spill into another column only after max-height reached

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make columns in from a block of text, but I only want the text to spill into a new column *after* it has reached the div's `max-height`.

```
.step-copy {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
   -moz-columns: 2;
        columns: 2;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

What happens, though, is that two perfectly even columns are created. The max height of the div is never reached.

Comment: Please post a JSfiddle, so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the columns a width as well. Take a look at this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpoGmJ see the code below

```
.columns {
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-columns: 300px 2;
   -moz-columns: 300px 2;
        columns: 300px 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by having:

```
{
display:block;
min-height:500px;
}
```

Simples :)